# Django cursor query to fetch total time

Tags: mysql, django

I have a mysql query to fetch total time of sessions. The query is

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)))) as total FROM session where helper_mode = 1
```

When i am running this query in my mysql GUI i am getting the correct result as

```
total   
35:34:27
```

But when i am running the same query using django cursor i am getting an exception like

> hour must be in 0..23

My cusror query is,

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)))) as total FROM session where helper_mode = 1")
```

Its happening when the total time exceeding 24 hours. Why i am getting this Exception? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the issue is the Python object (datatype) that the query column value is being assigned to.

A Python `time` object represents the time within a given day. So the value is restricted to values between `'00:00:00.000000'` and `'23:59:59.999999'`.  Values outside that range are invalid for a `time` object.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#time-objects

For storing a "duration", Python supports `timedelta` object:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: I think you are not cleared with my question. Both end_time,start_time are two columns in a table called sessions. Both have the same datatype timestamp. If the python restricted the time value, is there any other way to write this query effectively.

Comment: @sakeer:  The query is returning a column of MySQL datatype `TIME`. (That's the datatype returned by the `SEC_TO_TIME` function.) The issue is that the value being returned is over 24 hours, and that's a valid, expected return from MySQL. The error you're observing isn't a MySQL error. The error is being raised because whatever else your code is doing, it's attempting to assign a MySQL TIME value greater than 24 hours into a Python object which doesn't allow for values that large. That is why the exception is raised.

Comment: @sakeer: I thought that was the question you asked... why the exception is being raised. There are likely several different approaches to avoiding that exception. One easy one would be to remove the `SEC_TO_TIME` function in the query. Then the query would return a "total number of seconds" as a *numeric* datatype, and not a MySQL `TIME` datatype.

Comment: Thank you very much, its worked. You have saved my lots of effort